# Functional Implementation of Co-prime pairs in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

Program finds the number of pairs of co-primes in an array using 
functional concepts in Node.js

```
const assert = require('assert')

const gcd = (a, b) => (b != 0) ? gcd(b, a % b) : a

const co_prime = (a, b) => gcd(a, b) == 1

const co_prime_pairs = (_list) => {
    co_primes = []
    _list.map(
        (x, i) => _list.slice(i + 1)
                        .filter(y => co_prime(x, y))
                        .forEach(y => co_primes.push([x, y]))
        )
    return co_primes.length
} 

const main = () => {
    assert.equal(co_prime_pairs([1, 2, 3]), 3)
    assert.equal(co_prime_pairs([4, 8, 3, 9]), 4)
}

main()
```

Is the time complexity similar to that of the simple for-loop implementation?

Is there any scope for improving the time-complexity by using map and filter functions?

How is my choice of variable names?

How is code formatting?

Comment: Random thought: consider prime factoring the list elements, and then using hashes or something so you don't have to loop through each pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is my choice of variable names?

In general you used *snake case* for the function names which is more a ruby-style.

Additionally the function `co_prime_pairs` let me acept that it *return pairs of co-primes*. However it *returns a number of co-pairs* inside an array.

The variable `co_primes` is declared globally.

### `co_prime_pairs`

This function is not a pure function internally because `.forEach(y => co_primes.push([x, y]))` modifies `co_primes`.
I rewrite the function and spit the logic into:

1. build pairs
2. filter the co primes
3. return the length

The functions:

```
const filterCoPrimes = xss =>
    xss.filter(xs => isCoPrime(xs[0], xs[1]))

const buildPair = x => y =>
    [x, y]

const buildPairs = (xs, pairs) =>
    xs.length === 0 || xs.length === 1
        ? pairs
        : buildPairs(
            xs.slice(1), 
            pairs.concat(xs.map(buildPair(xs[0])))
        )
```

The chain:

```
const co_prime_pairs = xs =>
    filterCoPrimes(buildPairs(xs, [])).length
```

If we use `pipe` as a kind of [function composition](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-function-composition-20dfb109a1a0) it can be rewritten to:

```
const co_prime_pairs = pipe(
    buildPairs([]),
    filterCoPrimes,
    length
)
```

## Full working Example

- function calls:

```js
const gcd = (a, b) => 
  (b != 0) ? gcd(b, a % b) : a

const isCoPrime = (a, b) => 
  gcd(a, b) === 1

const filterCoPrimes = xss =>
  xss.filter(xs => isCoPrime(xs[0], xs[1]))

const buildPair = x => y =>
  [x, y]

const buildPairs = (xs, pairs) =>
  xs.length === 0 || xs.length === 1
      ? pairs
      : buildPairs(
          xs.slice(1), 
          pairs.concat(xs.map(buildPair(xs[0])))
      )

const co_prime_pairs = xs =>
  filterCoPrimes(buildPairs(xs, [])).length

console.log(co_prime_pairs([4, 8, 3, 9]))
```

- with pipe:

```js
const pipe = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => g(f(...args)))

const filter = fn => xs =>
    xs.filter(fn)

const map = fn => xs =>
    xs.map(fn)

const length = xs => 
    xs.length

const gcd = (a, b) => 
    (b != 0) ? gcd(b, a % b) : a

const isCoPrime = (a, b) => 
    gcd(a, b) === 1

const filterCoPrimes = xss =>
    xss.filter(xs => isCoPrime(xs[0], xs[1]))

const buildPair = x => y =>
    [x, y]

const buildPairs = pairs => xs =>
    xs.length === 0 || xs.length === 1
        ? pairs
        : buildPairs
            ( pairs.concat(xs.map(buildPair(xs[0]))) )
            ( xs.slice(1) )

const co_prime_pairs = pipe(
    buildPairs([]),
    filterCoPrimes,
    length
)
    
console.log(co_prime_pairs ([4, 8, 3, 9]))
```